# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.instabug.library

Tags: android, crash, instabug

I am getting crashes with this error

0-24 21:20:36.878 30082-30110/app.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: InstabugNetInit
10-24 21:20:36.878 30082-30110/app.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: app.com.myapp, PID: 30082
10-24 21:20:36.878 30082-30110/app.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.instabug.library.R$raw
10-24 21:20:36.878 30082-30110/app.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.instabug.library.network.toolbox.c.run(SSLUtil.java:27)
10-24 21:20:36.878 30082-30110/app.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

My app crashes after i added

dependencies {

```
compile 'me.iwf.photopicker:PhotoPicker:0.2.8@aar'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
```

}

below define github link of photopicker

https://github.com/donglua/PhotoPicker

can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Romit, how are you including the Instabug library? It's available on Maven Central, but it looks like you have integrated it manually? It looks like the library's resources are missing.

Comment: I have added instabug using gradle "compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1+'". Its working fine if i removed compile 'me.iwf.photopicker:PhotoPicker:0.2.8@aar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed issue after spending day. Extended Application class with `MultiDexApplication`